# How to make a local variable accessible outside the loop in java

Tags: java

I have a txt file in while one line is like this :

`"Execution Status: Pass"`

I want to take the value out : pass from here.

I am using below code :

```
String patternString1 = "(Execution) (Status:) (.*)";
Pattern patt1 = Pattern.compile( patternString1 );
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader( "c:\\abc.txt" ));
String line;
while ( (line = r.readLine()) != null ) {
    String g11 = null; 
    Matcher m1 = patt1.matcher( line );
    while ( m1.find() ) {
        g11=m1.group(3);
        System.out.println(g11+"HI1"); //Line1
    }
    System.out.println(g11+"HI1"); //Line2
}
```

While Line 1 is giving the desired output as "pass" I am not getting this expected output from Line 2.
Could any one of you please help me in accessing the local variable out of the loop?

Comment: Where are you declaring `g11`?

Comment: outside the inner while loop

Comment: an easier way would be simply to split `line` using `line.split (": ");`

Comment: Ok, help ous out here - what do you get in line 1 and 2, and what do you expect to get in line 2? Also, what is the declaration of g11?

Comment: Can you please include that in your code then? It's an important part of your problem.

Comment: String patternString1 = "(Execution) (Status:) (.*)";
  Pattern patt1 = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
  BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader("c:\\abc.txt"));
  String line;
  while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) { String g11=null;
        Matcher m1 = patt1.matcher(line);
        while (m1.find()) {
                                g11=m1.group(3);
                                 System.out.println(g11+"HI1");  -- line1
                                }
         System.out.println(g11+"HI1");   -- line2
   }

Comment: Hi Scary, this is not a single line txt file. It has many lines with different character. So i cant use that split. the matcher is better in this regard as all i can say

Comment: Hi Tassos, I am getting pass in line 1 while in line 2 I am getting null. I am expecting the same output in both line and that is pass

Comment: If the log in the inner loop is firing, then the code *should work*. Run a project clean, restart the IDE / machine and make sure you've not got any temporary files getting in the way.

Comment: Hi Christopher, The problem is that the txt file is multi line and not single line as presented. What is happening actually it selects one line to read and if it does not find any pattern as i mentioned it doesnt go in the inner loop but at the same time it is printing for line 2 as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare String g11 as a local variable at the start of your method

```
 String g11="";   -- declare g11 as a local variable
  String patternString1 = "(Execution) (Status:) (.*)";
  Pattern patt1 = Pattern.compile(patternString1);

Add the rest of your code here.........
```

Comment: thansk very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing following line:

```
while (m1.find())
```

to

```
 if(m1.find())
```

It should give the result you want

Comment: i dont think changing the loop from while to if solves the issue. I tried and its not working

Answer (score 0):

How about the easy way:

```
String result = line.replaceAll(".*: ", "");
```

This line says "replace everything up to and including *colon space* with nothing" (ie delete it).

Comment: Hi Bohemian, this is not a single line txt file. It has many lines with different character. So i cant use that split. the matcher is better in this regard as all i can say

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one instance of this match in single line then use `if` instead of `while (m1.find())` loop or `break` the loop once match is found.

Sample code:

```
while ( (line = r.readLine()) != null ) {
    String g11 = null; 
    Matcher m1 = patt1.matcher( line );
    if( m1.find() ) {
        g11=m1.group(3);            
    }
    if(g11 != null){
        System.out.println(g11+"HI1"); //Line2
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Raj, its not a good idea at all. what if we have another matcher say m2 then this conditions is invalid

Comment: @user3777979 I don't know what are you trying?